# Manage access to GCS buckets using VPC Service Controls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have three GCS buckets (A, B, C) in one project and these buckets are controlled by **VPC Service Controls** - only one specific IP address range can access these buckets.

Is it possible to make one of the buckets publicly available to anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VPC Service Control](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview#isolate) is a technical security control in GCP that allows administrators to configure different GCP projects and service groupings called [Service Perimeters.](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/transfer-with-vpc-sc#supported-configs) By default, a Service Perimeter configuration results in those GCP project’s services being restricted from being accessed outside of the Service Perimeter (ingress).So, when we create a perimeter around the storage, nobody will be able to access any resource of cloud storage outside the perimeter. In order for a user to access a Cloud Storage resource, you need to grant [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#choose_between_uniform_and_fine-grained_access) and Access Control Lists (ACLs) permissions.

As per your request, when three buckets are in VPC Control, we cannot make one bucket publicly accessible. This is the limitation of VPC and by default it will block access to the public for three buckets.